# Lotus Sametime 9 does not open chat window

Tags: lotus-notes, chat, lotus-sametime

Using lotus Lotus Sametime 9 I'm able to receive a chat message But when I try to start a chat my self the window does not open.

I already have updated to the last version of Java and .NET framework

Comment: Is it not opening at all or just not bringing it to the front?